# Powershell, How to match files names with partial names stored in text file

Tags: arrays, string, file, powershell

Sorry for the dump question as I am a beginner in PowerShell. We have a lot of coming files into a directory, and they are always increasing and decreasing in that directory because it is moved to another directory after we are done from using them.

We have a priority file list in a txt file which has only partial name of the file name.

For example, for the file name:

> 2017-06-5---666-12-05-01.txt

In the priority list, I have the partial name as `---666---`.

How can I check if the files in the folder are already in the priority list by using Powershell?

I wrote the below script since I need only the files which are older than a given time. But it is not working.

```
Get-ChildItem -path $Struct.Path  -filter $Struct.filter |
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $time} |
Where-Object {$_.Name -contains "*$PriorityList*"} |
ForEach-Object { $counterP++}
```

Comment: When you say that something didn't work, you have to say _how_ it didn't work.

Comment: it shows 0 files even though there is some of the priority files are there in the directory, so I believe my script is wrong in this line. since I am using the script to get only the files which are older than given time and it is working , but now I need to know if the files are older than a given time and if they are in the priority list, Thanks you for your comment

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code and now it is working perfectly

```
Get-ChildItem -path $Struct.Path  -filter $Struct.filter |
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $time} | ForEach-Object { If($_.name -
Match $Priorfilter) { $counterP++  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the file name in your example doesn't match the partial name. So let's assume that pattern is `"666"`. If you have several patterns, you can join them in one filter:

```
$PriorityList = "---666---","---555---"
$PriorityFilter = $PriorityList -join '|'
```

Then use this filter to check Name property:

```
Get-ChildItem -path $Struct.Path  -filter $Struct.filter |
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $time} |
Where-Object {$_.Name -match $PriorityFilter |
ForEach-Object { $counterP++}
```

The `-contains` operator works with a collection as left operand and do not accept wildcards for matching.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it always return 1 as a value, but there are multiple files in the directory which matches the priority files list?